# Importing sequence from previous code into another

Tags: python, list, sequence, equation

Here's my task:

There are two types of cards: red and blue. 6-10 cards are being drawn out and put back. Another 6-10 cards are drawn out. I created a sequence that would give all the possible outcomes for 6,7,8,9, and 10 cards. This is the sequence:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement 

def generate_sequence(): 
  box_1=['R','B']
  comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 6) 
  for i in list(comb): 
    print(i)

  comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 7) 
  for i in list(comb): 
    print(i)
    
  comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 8) 
  for i in list(comb): 
    print(i)
    
  comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 9) 
  for i in list(comb): 
    print(i)

  comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 10) 

  for i in list(comb): 
    print(i)
```

Now, I have to import the generated sequences into this equation I coded out.

```
#Draws 
first_draw = 
second_draw = 

#Before first draw

initial_estimate = 0.5
initial_variance = 1/12

#After first draw 

r_count = first_draw.count('R')
b_count = first_draw.count('B')


alpha = 1 + r_count
beta = 1 + b_count

e_of_theta = alpha/(alpha+beta)

surprise = ((e_of_theta - initial_estimate)**2)/(initial_variance)

var_theta = (alpha * beta)/ ((alpha + beta) **2 *(alpha + beta + 1))

#After second draw 

r_count = second_draw.count('R')
b_count = second_draw.count('B')

new_alpha = alpha + r_count 
new_beta = beta + b_count 

new_e_of_theta = new_alpha/(new_alpha + new_beta)

surprise = ((new_e_of_theta - e_of_theta)**2)/var_theta

print(surprise)
```

In the blank area where the first_draw and second_draw is, that is where I need to put in the sequences generated by the first code. I need all of the possible combinations of the sequences to be first_draw and second_draw, so I get a list of all the possible outcomes of the equation. However, I am struggling to insert those sequences into the first_draw and second_draw. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to 'draw' a random tuple from the list use this:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement 
import pandas as pd
import random

deckOrder=[]

box_1=['R','B']
comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 6) 
for i in list(comb): 
    deckOrder.append(i)

comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 7) 
for i in list(comb): 
    deckOrder.append(i)
    
comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 8) 
for i in list(comb): 
    deckOrder.append(i)
    
comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 9) 
for i in list(comb): 
    deckOrder.append(i)

comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 10) 
for i in list(comb): 
    deckOrder.append(i)

#Draw
    
first_draw = random.sample(deckOrder, 1)
second_draw = random.sample(deckOrder, 1)
```